# Vagrant VM Fails to Boot

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I have a Vagrant environment that requires me to forward port 80 so I bring it up under `sudo` on an OS X machine. This has always been fine until I recently upgraded to Vagrant 1.2.2. Now it fails to boot.

```
[default] Waiting for VM to boot. This can take a few minutes.
[default] Failed to connect to VM!
Failed to connect to VM via SSH. Please verify the VM successfully booted
by looking at the VirtualBox GUI.
```

Because I'm running under `sudo`, the machine never gets added to the Virtualbox GUI, but that's always been the case for this environment.

I don't get any indication that there was a problem with the additions -- a potential source of this error, from what I've read. I can bring things up just fine if I change to using port 8080 on the host machine. I can't use the app, but the VM itself loads up and provisions nicely.

As far as I can tell, the only thing that's changed is:

1. I upgraded my Vagrant version
2. I updated the project's `Vagrantfile` to use v2 syntax.

Anyone have any idea what I might be missing? I thought I'd be able to find this pretty easily, but it's quickly becoming a very real problem.

**UPDATE 27 JUN**

It appears that it's an SSH key issue if `VAGRANT_LOG=DEBUG` is to be believed:

```
DEBUG ssh: Checking key permissions: /Users/robwilkerson/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
 INFO ssh: SSH not up: #<Vagrant::Errors::SSHKeyBadOwner: The private key to connect to the machine via SSH must be owned
by the user running Vagrant. This is a strict requirement from
SSH itself. Please fix the following key to be owned by the user
running Vagrant:

/Users/robwilkerson/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key>
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["VBoxManage", "showvminfo", "3422bba7-8f35-42ad-ba1a-c127c6cb3cf6", "--machinereadable"]
```

I assume it wants a key owned by `root` since I'm under `sudo`, but if that's the case, why isn't it looking at `root`'s `~/.vagrant.d/`? Did v2 get more strict about this? I was able to `sudo vagrant up` just fine until the upgrade. Since this is my only dev environment that requires `sudo` to up, I'd rather not change key ownership. Is there another way?

Lots of questions, I know, but I could really use a hand understanding/fixing this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found a better solution to this than to toggle the owner of the private key when switching between this project and others. To make it suck just a little less, I created a `zsh` function:

```
vkey() { sudo chown "$*":staff ~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key; }
```

From the command line, I can update the key owner with this:

```
$ vkey <new_owner_username>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the ownership of the `vagrant.d` directory:

```
# cd ~
# sudo chown -R root .vagrant.d/
```

Comment: It will only worse the situation: Vagrant will fail with *The home directory you specified is not accessible. The home
directory that Vagrant uses must be both readable and writable.*

Comment: If you need to run vagrant as root (to bind to host port 80), this fix works.